# On my webserver i am hosting 2 applications and both ae applications use the same .aspxauth cookie

Tags: .net, asp.net

On my webserver i am hosting 2 applications and both applications use the same .aspxauth cookie. which is causing a problem. I dont want them to use same.aspxauth cookie. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the name of the Authenticatioin cookie (.aspxauth is default) is defined in the web.config.  Just change the value for the cookie name in one of the application's web.config.